# when i run "rails s" i get "dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file load -- gettext/rails (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I cant run "rails s" eny more and I cant understand why.
I work on windows.
When i try to run "rails s" i get this error:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file
 load -- gettext/rails (LoadError)
```

What should i do? What is the couse for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gettext gem ins't installed, did you just upgrade to rails 3 or create a new gemset?  Try running `gem install gettext` and then rerun `rails s`.

Comment: I try to reinstall the gem but the same happens... =/